# Crash with DatePicker and NSDate

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

I have mysterious crash when trying to launch my app on iPhone (*it perfectly valid works on Simulator though*). I think problem is in this 2 methods..:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [self getValueFromPicker];
}


-(void)getValueFromPicker{

    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];

    NSDate *birthDate = self.birthdayPicker.date;

    NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit
                                               fromDate:now
                                                 toDate:birthDate
                                                options:0];

    NSLog(@"Difference in years %i/", components.year);

}
```

App crash with **SIGABRT**  error, and there is a text i can see in a console: `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid parameter not satisfying: date'`

Please help me, i'am really have no idea what i did wrong, when i did the same thing on Simulator in console i can see difference in years from Now date and date, user picked.

Update:after i removed [self defaultBirthdayPickerDate]; in viewDidLoad section it start to work. But, now picker show current date, its not very convenient for picking birthday Date, now i still need to change its current date from now to past..

Comment: is the datepicker outlet connected?

Comment: Yeah.. @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIDatePicker *birthdayPicker; As i said it works on simulator and crash on device.. what a black magic it is?

Comment: change your call to viewDidAppear: method.The issue may be with picker date which is a view component

Comment: I tried to do as u suggest, but still crashing..

Comment: log both the values and check the output

Comment: May be some change in locale setting or something on your device. Check if it's the same. And check and post which exact line is causing the crash by adding an exception breakpoint or stepping through the code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mostly this types of error generated when you applies `nil` date: check values of `self.birthdayPicker.date` it is `nil` or/not ?? and give proper condition `if` you get `nil` value of `UIDatePicker.`

Comment: It crash because it always not == NULL. When i wrote [self.birthdayPicker setDate:date]; it crash, don't know why

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is here:

```
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit
                                               fromDate:now
                                                 toDate:birthDate
                                                options:0];
```

Your `fromDate` is higher than `toDate`.

Change it to:

```
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit
                                               fromDate:birthDate
                                                 toDate:now
                                                options:0];
```

Comment: It's not helped me to solve that issue, but still i change my code as u suggest and now i don't have to worry how to deal with negative numbers, thanks:)

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the locale of your NSDateFormatter.
Set up your iPhone settings with US locale and then set the 12/24 setting to any one option.
For that you have to look into the iphone settings panel.

Hope this works.

Comment: Visit 'settings' panel of the iphone and find the 'date and time' option

Answer (score 0):

I also have a method for setting default values for picker like this:

```
-(void)defaultBirthdayPickerDate{

    NSString *dateString = @"09-Oct-1987";
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"dd-MMM-yyyy";
    NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
    [self.birthdayPicker setDate:date];
}

-(void)viewDidLoad{
   [self defaultBirthdayPickerDate];
}
```

Full crash report in console is:

```
2013-03-05 13:15:12.982 DeathLine[2506:907] *** Assertion failure in -[_UIDatePickerView _setDate:animated:forced:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-2380.17/_UIDatePickerView.m:302
2013-03-05 13:15:12.985 DeathLine[2506:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid parameter not satisfying: date'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x325042a3 0x3a22197f 0x3250415d 0x32dd9ab7 0x344bdf15 0x344c6429 0x3458f989 0x35a6b 0x358db 0x3432b595 0x3438014b 0x34380091 0x3437ff75 0x3437fe99 0x3437f5d9 0x3437f4c1 0x3436db93 0x2908c33 0x3436d833 0x343f70c5 0x343f7077 0x343f7055 0x343f690b 0x343f6e01 0x3431f5f1 0x3430c801 0x3430c11b 0x360225a3 0x360221d3 0x324d9173 0x324d9117 0x324d7f99 0x3244aebd 0x3244ad49 0x360212eb 0x34360301 0x2dc21 0x3a658b20)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

Comment: in date picker the date should be in the below format: MMM d, y